# Backbone.js Comparator not sorting (Coffeescript)

Tags: javascript, sorting, backbone.js, coffeescript

I am trying to sort a collection by alphabetical order in Backbone.js using Coffeescript. The collection is the first 5 objects in a table that I want to display.

```
  preview = new Collections.Bananas(@model.get('bananas').slice(0,5))

  preview.comparator = (banana) -> banana.get("name")

  bananas = new BundleOfBananas.Bananas({collection: preview})
```

The objects are all displaying and I'm getting the proper data, it is just not being alphabetically arranged. Can anyone help me out with Backbone.js comparators? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Backbone collection sorts itself when one of two things happen:

1. You add some models and have a [`comparator`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-comparator) defined.
2. You manually call [`sort`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-sort) on the collection and have a `comparator` defined.

When you add your models:

```
preview = new Collections.Bananas(@model.get('bananas').slice(0,5))
```

there is, presumably, no `comparator` defined on the collection so no sorting is done. Then you assign the `comparator` property:

```
preview.comparator = (banana) -> banana.get("name")
```

but don't call `preview.sort()` to tell the collection to sort itself.

You have two basic options:

1. Define the comparator *before* adding anything. You can make the `comparator` function a part of the collection definition:

   ```
   class Collections.Bananas extends Backbone.Collection
       comparator: (banana) -> banana.get('name')
       # as you have now...
   ```

   or just use a property since you're sorting by a model property:

   ```
   class Collections.Bananas extends Backbone.Collection
       comparator: 'name'
       # as you have now...
   ```

   and then instantiate your collection:

   ```
   new Collections.Bananas(@model.get('bananas')[0..4])
   ```

   That will give you an automatically sorted collection. If you want to manually assign the `comparator` as you're doing now then:

   ```
   preview = new Collections.Bananas
   preview.comparator = 'name'
   preview.reset(@model.get('bananas')[0..4])
   ```
2. Manually call `sort`:

   ```
   preview = new Collections.Bananas(@model.get('bananas')[0..4])
   preview.comparator = 'name'
   preview.sort()
   ```

Comment: This is great, thanks a lot! Creating the comparator function where I defined the collection worked very well. Much appreciated!

Comment: I actually do have another question. Say I always want one Banana (the primary banana, in the DB. It has an is_primary attribute) to show up at the top, regardless of it's alphabetical placement. How would this be achieved?

Comment: You'd have to use a two argument `comparator` function for that, if your comparator is `(a,b) -> ...` then it behaves like an `Array.prototype.sort` comparator function.